# Extending 2D array - Java

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures

I have a network of nodes. I can traverse from one node to another using a token. I have a function that with a given initial node and a token outputs a list of all possible nodes I can traverse to.

```
public int[] checkToken(int initial_pos, String token) {
    magic_happens();
    return possible_nodes_list;
}
```

My problem is the following: I am given an initial node: e.g. 27 and then a list of tokens. I check for all possible nodes I can move to from initial node with first token. After that, I check all possible nodes I can move to with the next token but instead of from the initial node, it is now from the result of the first iteration. After that I must print the entire paths from initial value to ultimate final. e.g.

```
27 -token1- 40 -token2- 52 -token3- 13
27 -token1- 58 -token2- 69 -token3- 8
27 -token1- 58 -token2- 69 -token3- 72
27 -token1- 67 -token2- 10 -token3- 90
```

So not only must I increment the array depending on the amount of possible paths I get after calling `checkToken()` but I must add it to the immediate row below so I can print results like above. I cant wrap my head around this. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see how the site works and what questions are on topic here.  See also: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Pro tip: work with lists instead of arrays (linked-list is better in your case), you'll be able to add elements and increase the size of the list by simply calling `add()` method while with arrays you'll need to copy the entire array to a bigger one, add the new element and update the reference to the array to point to the new one. A "bit" more work...